# Question with prefer - usage of or as conjunction

Tags: questions, conjunctions

I have two sentences. I want to make questions about preferences. Should I use or as conjunction?

1. I prefer to run rather than cycle.

- Do you prefer to run rather than cycle?
- Do you prefer to run or cycle?

2. I prefer running to cycling.

- Do you prefer running to cycling?
- Do you prefer running or cycling?

Which questions from the two options are grammatically correct?

Comment: You seem to have two different questions and also you show no research.

Comment: @Lambie I did some research, but information I've found is not consistent. Different usages in different places. The both sentences I provided are about the same topic - usage of or in the question about preference.

Comment: You should try and present what you found. I will answer the question for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For comparisons, you can use either or or rather than.

These are right:
Do you prefer to run **rather than** cycle?
Do you prefer to run **or** cycle?

So, are these:
Do you prefer running **to** cycling?
Do you prefer running **or** cycling?

In many cases, some verbs take the to infinitive or the gerund.

I love to swim.
I love swimming.

Those are basically the same.

Other verbs that do this are like and hate,

Comment: What if I have a noun instead of verb. For instance. I prefer dogs to cats. The correct question would be with to, or with or as a conjunction?

Comment: Same thing. Do you prefer dogs to cats? OR: Do you prefer dogs or cats?

Comment: In "I love swimming", "swimming" is strictly speaking ambiguous between a verb and a noun, but verb is the more salient interpretation (“I like to swim”). Noun interpretation can be forced by adjectival premodification, as in "occasional swimming".

Comment: @BillJ I love swimming, refers to the fact of swimming. I love to swim creates a link between I love and the bare noun. See the French linguist: Grammaire linguistique de l'anglais  4 mars 1998 de Henri Adamczewski (Auteur)

Comment: I reject that claim. It can also refer to the act of swimming, and that's why it's ambiguous. It's a noun in "I love occasional swimming", but it's a verb in "I love swimming vigorously every day in the lake".